# Remove scrollbar at right from multiline TextField - Flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollbar, textfield

I have TextField `purchaseCommentField()` within the structure as below:

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context)
      {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: CommonUtils.endEditing(context),
          child: Container(
              width: _width,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ....
                    ...
                    Visibility(
                        visible: _additionalInfo != null,
                        child: purchaseCommentField()
                    ),
                    rowSpacer(16.0),
                    actionButton(context)
                  ],
                )
              )
          ),
        );
      }

 Widget purchaseCommentField()
  {
    return TextField(
      controller: _purchaseCommentController,
      minLines: 1,
      maxLines: null,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Additional Info',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When I focus textfield, I got unwanted scrollbar at right inside the field:

[image]

This issue occured when I set `fontSize:14.0`. When I remove that or set fontSize to 16.0 then there is no scrollbar at right:

[image]

Is there a way to remove that scrollbar in textfield ?

Answer (score 3):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110035) on github regarding this.
For now you can fix this by creating a custom `ScrollBehavior` and overriding `buildScrollbar` method:

```
class CustomScrollBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  const CustomScrollBehavior();

  @override
  Widget buildScrollbar(context, child, details) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

And then wrap your TextField with `ScrollConfiguration` widget:

```
return ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: const CustomScrollBehavior(),
  child: TextField(
    // Your text-field params
  ),
);
```

This works for `TextFormField` too.

Answer (score -1):

try using `TextFormField`,

```
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: textController,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.trim().isEmpty) {
                          return _reportTypeModel.language.msgEnterDesc;
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                      maxLength: 500,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: _reportTypeModel.language.description,
                      ),
                      minLines: 4,
                      maxLines: 6,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    ),
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @iAkki try to post parent widget code too because even your code works perfectly for me. maybe culprit can be any of parent widget!!

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question with parent widget. Please have a look.

Comment: That whole stuff is being displayed as content of showDialog().

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, I had to remove ` onTap: CommonUtils.endEditing(context),` because I don't know where it is imported from? But code worked just fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203651/discussion-between-iakki-and-ravinder-kumar).